# why I cannot make element in array to be null?

Tags: scala

I want write method to clear this array, so I choose get every element in array and make this to be null, but compiler says this element must be T,  In the document, null is a subtype of every type except of those of value class, and I have defined T extends AnyRef, but it does't work.Is there any way to make this work?
scala version: 2.11.12

```
class CuckooHashTable[T<: AnyRef: ClassTag](val hashFamily: HashFamily[T]) {
  private var data:Array[T] = new Array[T](DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE)
  private val numHashFunctions = hashFamily.getNumberOfFunctions
  private var currentSize: Int = _
  def this(hashFamily: HashFamily[T], size: Int){
    this(hashFamily)
    data = new Array[T](size)
  }
  def doclear = {
    for(i <- data.indices){
      //error line
      data(i) = null
    }
  }
}
object CuckooHashTable{
  private val MAX_LOAD = 0.4
  private val ALLOWED_REHASHS = 1
  private val DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE = 101
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by "clearing" the array? Putting `null` values in the array is not going to be the answer anyway, and especially in Scala where you don't expect `null` to exist!

Comment: If doing Scala, you should probably get rid of all the mutable stuff and embrace the power of the language: keep everything immutable.

Comment: Mutability, `null`, `Array` all are bad practices in **Scala**; really if you are going to write **Java** code use **Java** - Anyways, the solution tp your issue is this `[T >: Null <: AnyRef : ClassTag]`

Comment: I believe author wanted to implement some hash table as an exercise (this is _literally_ in the example). By definition it would be mutable, so I see no reason for scorning them for it. Mutability and nulls are wrong if you use it as your first tools of choice, it is valid use case for libraries' internals especially when it doesn't leak outside.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok `null` is never a valid use case for internals in Scala when there is `Option`, and `Array` is also questionable when there is `Vector`.

Comment: So, if you were implementing data structures form Cormen using raw primitives, you would give your professor and assignment when your hash table is implemented using `Vector`s or `Array[Option[T]]` to avoid arrays/nulls? Boy, you're gonna be shocked when you take a look at how standard library internals or Cats Effect were implemented. If your reply was not a trolling joke I cannot take you as serious engineer anymore.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok If I was the professor I would fail anyone who used `null` or `Array` for the internals of a simple Scala hash table implementation unless I had explicitly said that it should be optimised for performance.

Answer (score 0):

`T` extends `AnyRef`, but that does not mean that `T` is a supertype of `Null` for every `T`.

It is not type sound because there is one type in Scala that is not a supertype of `Null`, which is `Nothing`. For example, one could do this:

```
val cht = new CuckooHashTable[Nothing](new HashFamily[Nothing])
```

Since `Nothing` is the bottom type in Scala (the subtype of every other type), and `Null` is not a subtype of `Nothing`, this is not type sound.

A workaround would be to have `Null` as the lower bound of type `T`:

```
class CuckooHashTable[T >: Null <: AnyRef: ClassTag](val hashFamily: HashFamily[T])
```

Now `Nothing` is not allowed anymore, the code becomes type sound, and your code compiles.